# Run all possible models in a r loop

Tags: r, loops, model

I have 3 independent variables (IV), 1 dependent variable (DV), and an IV `group`, which the other 5 DVs are nested within. I am exploring the model structures (in Hierarchical Linear Model) by trying out all combinations of the 5 IVs to the models in R. Currently, my method is writing manually the model structures like the following:

```
glmer(DV ~ IV1 + (1|group), data = df)
glmer(DV ~ IV2 + (1|group), data = df)
glmer(DV ~ IV3 + (1|group), data = df)
glmer(DV ~ IV1 + IV2 + (1|group), data = df)
glmer(DV ~ IV1 + IV3 + (1|group), data = df)
# etc...
```

How can I elegantly run all possible models in a loop?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: I guess `dredge` from MuMIn can do all model combinations for `glmer` too.

Comment: Or you could make a full model and use `drop1`.

Comment: `drop1` will not solve the problem since  after dropping you still need to add it back at some point. eg if you have 1,2,3 then drop 3, you will have 1,2 so you will have to add it back to have 1,3 or even 2,3

Answer (score 1):

You can also use combinations:

```
 s=paste0("IV",1:3)
 A=Map(combn,list(s),1:3,c(function(x)reformulate(c(x,"(1|group)"),"D")),simplify=F)
 rapply(A,glmer,data=df)
```

If you do not care of long line codes, then you can as well include the `glmer` function in the first line:

```
 Map(combn,list(s),1:3,c(function(x)glmer(reformulate(c(x,"(1|group)"),"D"),data=df)),simplify=F)
```

Also you can break the above code into various lines:

```
s=paste0("IV",1:3)
A=Map(combn,list(s),1:3,c(function(x)paste0(c(x,"(1|group)"),collapse="+")),simplify=F)
B=rapply(A,reformulate,response="D")
lapply(B,glmer,data=df)
```

I do not recommend breaking it down further, although its possible

Comment: This is very good, but would be even more helpful with working code using data available within an R package.